# Visual FoxPro - Tables Count

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am using Visual Fox Pro 9.0  and new to it.
Please help with how to get no of tables present in a fox pro database ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is ADbObjects() function to get various database objects. For getting tables set its second parameter to 'TABLE'. ie:

```
* Assuming database is open and current database
Local Array laTables[1]
Local ix
For ix = 1 To Adbobjects(laTables,"TABLE")
    ? laTables[m.ix]
Endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

A Klutzy way to get that info, (if you have the Fox IDE - and can get to the command window) is:
CLOSE theDatabase (that's the database you want to see - checking if it's open)
USE theDatabase Exclusive
BROWSE

You'll then get a list of the tables in the database.  Not pretty, but effective

Answer (score 0):

this will print number of tables in database

```
?ADBOBJECTS(databaseName, "TABLE")
```